# Blender 2.8 - light / lamp object

Tags: light

I must be missing something completely obvious.

In Blender 2.8, starting with a new scene (File > New > General) I am looking at a cube, light and camera.  The light doesn't appear to do anything.  If I move the light, nothing changes.  Changing the settings for the light doesn't seem to make a difference, nor does changing the render engine.

I would like to get the light working, so that I can see shadows.  The shadows should move when I move the light.  I should get different results when I change the type of light or its settings.

Your suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the Eevee render engine is turned on, and make sure you're using the rendered view and not solid view. the light should affect the cube after that (although if you want reflections or anything you need to turn that on in screen space reflections)
[image]

[image]

If this doesnt work it may be due to hardware limitations